# Amazon ec2 SES with sendmail path configuration

Tags: amazon-ec2, sendmail, amazon-ses

I have setup my ec2 instance with SES documented at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/scripts-mtas-sendmail.html

everything is working accordingly except that the last point

```
sudo /usr/bin/sendmail -f from@example.com to@example.com
```

throws error saying  /usr/bin/sendmail: No such file or directory

instead using path with "sbin" i am able to send mail successfully.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sendmail -f from@example.com to@example.com
```

how can i configure php to use this path instead. setting my php ini with 
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail;
 didnt work..

Comment: Solved it by creating a simlink from sbin to bin :                   ln -s /usr/sbin/sendmail /usr/bin/sendmail

Comment: Could report it as a SES bug? [wrong path to sendmail binary]

Comment: well - i really don't know if it was my sendmail installation configuration, would post that though. Thanks for the comments!